# Google Cloud new cluster generation failure.

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have been trying to create a new cluster using both the Web UI and the following command:
`gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-2 --zone europe-west1-b --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 --master-boot-disk-size 50 --num-workers 2 --worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 --worker-boot-disk-size 50 --project <project-name>`

The cluster consists of one master node and 2 worker nodes and it is a pretty small cluster. The virtual machines  are generated and are running properly. However, the  cluster generation fails.

The error messages shown during the cluster-generation point me to the file "dataproc-startup-script_output". The only error message I have found is   `Error: "--max_wait_seconds" does not look like a port` in that file.

The number of VMs that I have is 5. Single machines can be created and run successfully. In the recent past (few days ago), I was able to create a cluster with no problems. That cluster is now deleted however. Is there a limit to how many clusters one can create?

Comment: Does this happen consistently? If it happens again, can you run `gcloud dataproc clusters diagnose cluster-2` and send the resulting tarball to dataproc-feedback@google.com? There's no limit to the number of clusters you can create; if you hit quota limits then that should display a quota error message before ever trying to create the cluster.

Comment: Also, did you change any project network settings since the last time it deployed successfully? Any use of init actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the findings from following up separately by email thread, in general if:

1. It takes longer than 10 minutes or so to fail, and
2. You've changed project network settings at all

Then a potential culprit is network misconfiguration. In general, Dataproc clusters require full internal IP networking access to each other, and it's typical to have a firewall rule in your Google Compute Engine network which opens all of `udp:1-65535,tcp:1-65535,icmp` but limited to the internal-IP "source IP range".

In this case, the project was indeed missing a necessary rule due to a minor typo/misconfiguration, where a `default-allow-internal` rule accidentally limited the source IP range with a complete mask of `/32`.

If you're not doing advanced VPN configuration or cross-project networking, re-adding a simple `10.0.0.0/8 udp:1-65535;tcp:1-65535;icmp` firewall rule should work. If you're doing more advanced networking, you'll likely want to restrict the source range to be a bit more specific, for example something if your network's IPv4 range is `10.128.0.0/16` then you should set your "allow internal" firewall to use that `10.128.0.0/16` source range as well.

Adding firewall rules through the [cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/add) provides convenience methods for selecting applicable Source IP ranges, especially convenient when you have subnetworks that are messy to enumerate manually.